# Align TextView to center of RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

in my application i have a Relative Layout and inside 3 textview. I would place the 3 textview 
, 1 to left, 1 to right and 1 to center.

**AS IS**

[image]

**TO BE**

[image]

THIS MY LAYOUT XML

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
     >
 <TextView

      android:id="@+id/girone"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="20dip"
      style="@style/NomeSquadra"

  />

     <TextView

            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dip"
            android:layout_below="@+id/girone"
            style="@style/NomeSquadra"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        />



       <TextView

            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
            android:id="@+id/vs"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dip"
            android:layout_below="@+id/girone"
            style="@style/NomeSquadra"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        />



       <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
            android:id="@+id/away"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/vs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dip"
            android:layout_below="@+id/girone"
            style="@style/NomeSquadra"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

@style/NomeSquadra :

```
 <style name="NomeSquadra" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">#C0C0C0</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">#C0C0C0</item>
</style>
```

How place textview with id "vs" to center of the relative layout (center screen)?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this following layout structure with yours...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/girone"
        style="@style/NomeSquadra"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/home"
        style="@style/NomeSquadra"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/girone"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vs"
        style="@style/NomeSquadra"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/girone"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/away"
        style="@style/NomeSquadra"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/girone"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/vs"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: see my updated answer...I think you will get it right.

Comment: there is tick mark show in left side of answer click that.

Comment: just tick to the answer's left corner as accepted...after accepting answer, it will show a green tick mark.

Answer (score 1):

Please Use the code in your TextView:

```
    <TextView

            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
            android:id="@+id/vs"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dip"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/girone"
            style="@style/NomeSquadra"

        />
```

Comment: android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"   Replace this

Answer (score 1):

Try this one it will work what you expect

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="3"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="2" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @user3336884 just copy and paste this code in one new xml and see what the result is...

Comment: and make sure you are using relative layout.

Comment: i try but receive the same error....
view here http://imageshack.com/a/img34/8602/3j4v.png

Comment: type layout and press ctrl+space button in windows ..there you see this parentlayoutEnd suggestion..

Answer (score 0):

try this Code for TextView Whose id= **android:id="@+id/vs**

```
<TextView
       android:id="@+id/vs"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="25dip"
       android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/away"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/away"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`

**Editted:**

Try the below code in your layout xml file

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:background="#ff6a0a0a"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="center first row" />

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="3"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:background="#ff6a0a0a"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="2afasfasdf middle row  content" />

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="3"
    />
</RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:background="#ff6a0a0a"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="thrid row" />

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="3"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I tried using `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` as suggested on this thread, to display text when AdapterView (ListView, GridView etc) is empty, but this didn't work:

Solution was to use `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolsGridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/emptyGridViewText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:text="Not items to display at the moment. Please check again soon"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="15sp"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

remember to use `android:gravity="center"` to properly align text

[image]